# Rails app root_path set with 2 CSS files when user signed in & out (Rails)

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I have a static landing page and wanted to integrate it to my rails app root_path when user_not_signed_in. The landing page has it's own css file rules - different from the rails app. Is there a way to set it so that my rails apps application.css is not affected by the landing page main.css? I have Devise setup for user authorization.

In my layout/application.rb link to css:

In my landing page I have a standard:

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong one possible solution could be, you can make a home controller that just show pages available for guest users. In that controller you can make any action and check if user_signed_in? `do whatever you want` or else redirect_to `your new page`.

Comment: The landing page has its own CSS styles - when I add it the landing page CSS file and the user logga in their admin is broken because of the landing page styles being different from admin styles